# How to make bold italics of a discord bot reply?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make a date and time string command with bold text, I know it sounds quite easy but I don't know how to do it.

Discord.js@14.6.0

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('date')
        .setDescription('Displays the date'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const currentDate = new Date();
        return interaction.reply(currentDate.toLocaleString('en-DK', {
            hour12: false,
        }));
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discord supports markdown so you should be able to just add `**` to format it to bold text.

```js
return interaction.reply(`**${currentDate.toLocaleString('en-DK', {
    hour12: false,
})}**`);
```